# Save form v.s submit form in infopath2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath

Hi 
I am new to Infopath ,SharePoint2010.
I have a form library where user can complete a form. It allows user to save incomplete form. Once they complete the form , it will allow user to submit the form. However, When saving the form , it will create new form and save into the form library ,when submit the form it will create another form in the same form library. How can I make sure that when user submit the form , it will use the current saved form.

Can this achievable or I am asking too much?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best practice is to use submit to Sharepoint rather than save.

That way you can control where and with what name the documents are saved.

Also it is one click for the users.

It sounds like you need to turn off the reminder to save in the form options. That way the users will not be prompted.

To keep the file name from changing you need to only calculate it when the form is initially completed.

Create a file name filed in the form.  If it is blank on open set it to username+date.  That way the first time the form is opened it is set but after that it does not change.  Then in your submit data connection use the filename field as the file name.